# Compiling *.ts files in a specific directory to a single file

Tags: typescript

I know it is possible to compile all your typescript files to one file using the `"outFile": "../../built/local/tsc.js"` compiler option. But is it possible to just use that to compile every typescript file in a specific directory and compile the rest the default way?

Comment: You can create separate `tsconfig.json` files and specify different a `rootDir` in each, you can also use `exclude` and `include` as well as various combinations of configuration inheritance and command line arguments to accomplish this. Can you explain a bit more about what you want to achieve specifically? There are many ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can, but to make it work properly you will have met some requiremenst,
let's assume you have `src` folder and `src/sub` folder which you want to build it in one `.js` file

1. `src/sub` folder should have `index.ts` file, which should have named exports for each of its public interface (methods, consts, enums, etc.)
2. all other files in `src` folder (outside of `sub` folder), should import ONLY from `sub/index.ts`
3. in `src` folder should be 2 `tscofig`s

   - one for `src/sub` (`tsconfig.sub.json` which has to import
     `./sub/index.ts` and `"outFile": "../dist/sub.js"`)
   - second for `src` (`tsconfig.json`, which should explicetely `exclude` `src/sub`)
4. Order of build could make a difference